# Print array in array twig

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, html-table, twig

I want to print some values of an array which is inside another array like the first capture in a Twig, but I got an error:

> "Notice: Array to string conversion".

[image: array inside other array]

I prove with a join but the result isn't what I want, I expected the values of the second array become separated by a `<td></td>` inside a table and I got a result like is on the second capture in the first table.

This is my current template:

```
<table class="table-bordered" width="100%">
    <tbody class="text-center">
        <tr>
            <th>Usuarios</th>
            <th>Preguntas</th>
        </tr>
        {% for reporte in discriminacionPregunta %}
        <tr></tr>
        <tr>
            <th>{{reporte.cedula}}</th>
            <td><b>{{reporte.nombrepregunta|join('~ ~')}}</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <td>{{reporte.respuestas|join('~ ~')}}</td>
        </tr>
        {%endfor%}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the image of the result:

[image: Result]

If someone could help me on that I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm guessing there is a `null`-value in one of your elements.  You could rely on  the filter `default`, e.g. `{{reporte.respuestas|default([]) | join('~ ~')}}`

Comment: @DanielViteri you should be edit your posts regardless of how little reputation you have.